# Magento 1.9 How to change CSV Separator

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export

**I want to export records in CSV files.**

All data are Separated with `,`

I want it be Separated by `;`

Answer (score 1):

There should be a method streamWriteCsv called several times in your grid class (or in one of the parents - I think it should be a Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid).

You can pass your custom delimiter to all the method calls as a second parameter (enclosure is 3rd).